# Where is the Monero blockchain stored on Linux build?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, linux

I'm a Linux newbie and I don't know where monerod is storing the blockchain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blockchain is stored in $HOME/.bitmonero

For testnet, it'll be in $HOME/.bitmonero/testnet

You can select a different directory with the --data-dir option if needed, eg:

./monerod --data-dir /var/tmp/monero

Comment: `$HOME/.bitmonero` is another way of writing:

`/home/yourUserName/.bitmonero`

Note that the period in front of bitmonero means that it is a hidden directory. If you're in the terminal, type this to see all directories, including the hidden ones:

`ls -lha`

The actual database is:

`$HOME/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb`

Comment: Is there an environmental variable that can also set the --data-dir if --data-dir is not passed?

Comment: If you mean setting an environment variable, and have the code use this instead of --data-dir, then no.